# Why do my Illustrator linked files look desaturated on Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, color-profile

I have a Photoshop file with only a layer in it, the layer is a linked Illustrator file. Both files have the same color mode, and assigned color profile. The problem is that Photoshop is showing all the colors in the embedded file a bit desaturated.

I have turned off the option Proof Colors in both applications, the color mode is RGB, and the assigned profile is sRGB (IEC61966-2.1) for both documents.

[This](https://www.anonfiles.cc/file/a808205d32feff529e88b1c38836b0e5) is a stripped-down version of the file. For some reason Illustrator is showing me the same desaturated image than Photoshop but only in the preview when exporting the image for the web, so what troubles me is that the image I see in realtime on Illustrator is not the same that will be exported nor what will be shown on Photoshop.

This is a screenshot with both Photoshop and Illustrator set to Proof Color in Monitor RGB

[image]

Also the color settings for Photoshop (left side) and Illustrator (right side)

[image]

Comment: General comment: Use Adobe Bridge to set all your variables and presets so they will transfer to Adobe products (Illustrator, Photoshop, etc.) seamlessly. This will avoid situations such as this.

Comment: The suggestion by @Stan is an excellent one. In Bridge you can synchronise your colour settings to avoid these problems.

Comment: @Stan you should really turn that into an answer, seriously, it's probably the way to fix the OPs problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These look identical to me when opening in PS, and when opening the Smart Objects in Illustrator.  There is a possibility that your proofing options in PS and AI don't match - set both to "Monitor RGB", and see if that makes a difference.

To change the proof setup click View > Proof Setup (same options in PS and AI).

Comment: I attached a screenshot showing how the images look in both applications with Proof Color set to Monitor RGB, also tried a different monitor and the images do appear identical. So, it seems there is a bug or something related to that particular monitor. I'll try to patch both applications with the latest update.

Comment: @rraallvv Hmmm . . . have you calibrated your monitor and generated a monitor profile?  That could be the issue.  If you haven't, then try setting the proof settings to Windows/Macintosh RGB in both applications.  Does that fix it or are they still different?  Also make sure you have "proof colours" enabled.

Comment: Yes, I've calibrated both monitors, each have a different color profile. Also tried setting both to the same color profile, but the problem persists. It seems a bug in the way Illustrator handles the monitor's color profile to render the images. I'll try the latest version for both applications.

Comment: @rraallvv I have to say when looking at your examples closer in the update, it looks like it's PS that has the problem.  These look like CMYK colours, the colours in AI look like RGBs.  It might be worthwhile investigating your colour setting preferrences in Edit > Color Settings, and make sure both AI and PS are the same.

Comment: I've attached the color settings, also asked a related question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/294314/36642)